# How to remove spacing between images in recycleview?

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

Hi would like to ask if anyone know whats' wrong with recycleview having so much spacing between images? The following is how i tried using margin to control the spaces however it seems not the right solution to my problem.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/galleryRecyclerView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_below="@id/displayGalleryView"
    android:longClickable="false" />
```

And the image xml:

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageGalleryView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I used marginLeft to control the spaces and it worked before i integrate other features, it's so strange.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVYtU.jpg)

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryRecyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(layoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewItemDecorator(1));

    RecyclerView.Adapter imageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(mGalleryFolder);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce gap between items in recycler view...

use this as inner class .

```
public class RecyclerViewItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int spaceInPixels;

        public RecyclerViewItemDecorator(int spaceInPixels) {
            this.spaceInPixels = spaceInPixels;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                                   RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            outRect.left = spaceInPixels;
            outRect.right = spaceInPixels;
            outRect.bottom = spaceInPixels;
            if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
                outRect.top = spaceInPixels;
            } else {
                outRect.top = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

call

list.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewItemDecorator(1));

before setting the adapter

Comment: make sure you used valid parameter. If the code won't work then try to use margintop with -ve values.  Hope this will give you a solution.

Comment: i'm using LinearLayoutManager! It's marginLeft but it won't work! I'm trying ViewPager method..

Comment: Ok. You can use listview instead of recycler view. It's possible to remove space between elements in listview.